# ¿como mostrar los resultados de un consulta en mysql con php en una tabla de html?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

lo que necesito es que al ejecutar una consulta a la base de datos, este resultado se muestre en una tabla y en cada columna lo que corresponde, esta hecho con php y mysql les paso lo que estaba haciendo

```
   $query = 'SELECT DISTINCT per.PERSC_Nombre as nombre , per.PERSC_ApellidoPaterno as apellido_paterno ,per.PERSC_ApellidoMaterno as apellido_materno
FROM cji_paciente pa
JOIN cji_persona per ON per.PERSP_Codigo = pa.PERSP_Codigo
JOIN cji_consulta con ON con.PACI_Codigo = pa.PACI_Codigo
JOIN cji_diagnostico dg ON dg.CONS_Codigo = con.CONS_Codigo
JOIN cji_diagnostico_fase dgf ON dgf.DIAG_Codigo = dg.DIAG_Codigo
JOIN cji_emprestablecimiento eme ON eme.EESTABP_Codigo = con.COMPP_Codigo
WHERE eme.EESTABP_Codigo =  "11"
AND dgf.FASDIA_TipoDias =  "2"/* FASDIA_TipoDias=0 lunes a sabado(fase 1) FASDIA_TipoDias=1 lun-mir-vier FASDIA_TipoDias=2 mar-jue-sa FASDIA_TipoDias=3 lu a sabado */
AND dgf.FASDIA_FlagFase =  "1"
AND con.PROD_Codigo =  "30852"
AND NOT 
EXISTS (
SELECT * 
FROM cji_consulta
WHERE PACI_Codigo = pa.PACI_Codigo
AND CONS_FechaRegistro = CURDATE( )
)';
$result = mysql_query($query) or die('Consulta fallida: ' . mysql_error());
$rows   = mysql_fetch_row($result);

?>

<table border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>Apellido Paterno</th>
                <th>Aperllido Materno</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php
            foreach ($rows as $row) {
        ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row[0]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row[1]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row[2]; ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php 
        }
         ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Que errores te marca? Te recomiendo que leas algo sobre Active Record https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/active_record.html

Answer (score 1):

Ya que estas dentro de la misma página puedes hacer lo siguiente colocar un ***while*** dentro de la tabla para que se te llene te dejo el ejemplo es solo la parte del html no la del código php:

```
<table border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>Apellido Paterno</th>
                <th>Aperllido Materno</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php
            while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
        ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row['nombre']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['apellido_paterno']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['apellido_materno']; ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php 
        }
         ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

> Nota: En tu etiqueta colocas codeigniter, si es para el framework. El código seria distinto.

Answer (score 0):

sino estoy mal creo que lo que usas esta bien. Pero debes de pasar esa cadena html que contiene tu tabla con tus datos a un método en JS y este te muestre tu tabla dentro de un div o lo que sea.

```
Mostrar(){
  $.ajax({
                data:  parametros,
                url:   'realizasConsulta.php',
                type:  'post',
                beforeSend: function () {
                        $("#resultado").html("Procesando, espere por favor...");
                },
                success:  function (response) {
                        $("#resultado").html(response);
                }
        });
}
```

Debes usar JQuery para que funcione. Espero te sirva

## resultado es el elemento en donde vas a mostrar tu tabla, ya sea un div o lo que sea